# Can anyone identify this "pixelated" type font? I tried every online identifier

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I have been trying for far too long to find this font. I've found some very similar, where the G and A match, but then the rest do not.

I have tried all the font recognition tools I know, including the ones written in the [font identification requirements post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366), except for the ones that require a download.

What's noticable:

1. The `A` is mirrored, has two 4x5 empty spaces, and is pointy
2. The `S` is mirrored (horizontal then vertical)
3. The `T` has a thicker "stem" than the top part

Unfortunately there is no website attached to this font. It's found on an image I found, so I can't even check the font-family.

I'm almost at the point where I suspect they used different fonts, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I don't think automatic font ID sites will work well for bitmap fonts. Perhaps better to search through [a list of bitmap fonts](https://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php?text=STREANG&fpp=200#null) to find as close a match as possible, or perhaps even consider making your own font.

Comment: If you end up recreating the font [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/142745/84899) might help.

Comment: @BillyKerr I thought about creating my own font, but since I actually just need to turn the above image into a vector, I think it's too much.

Comment: @Wolff Oh dang okay, that actually seems quite easy

Comment: Oh, if that's the case you can quickly draw it in a vector drawing application. Don't follow the lines of the image, but construct it from squares, merge the squares and that's it.