# Font from 1986 or earlier used in OrCAD

Tags: typography, font-identification, vintage

Honestly I know nothing about fonts, I tried my best to find it online, anyway I'm looking for a font used in this schematic. The only hint I have is from FAQ where the author of the schematic below answered question about what software he used for his schematics.

> Orcad v1.25 from circa 1986.

[source to the FAQ](https://www.devrs.com/gb/faqs.php)
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Related question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/142744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a brand-name font, it's a monospaced bitmap font, one in which the font is recorded as pixels rather than as lines and arcs. I'm afraid these designs are generally designed or licensed for the technical needs of the specific software used. I'm not aware of what companies licensed bitmap fonts. Someone who'd know would probably more come from an engineering/software business background than a graphic design background. If you absolutely had to know what font this was, I would seriously suggest reaching out to engineers who worked for this company on LinkedIn, they're in the best position to know. (Only if you had to know, I stress again, I don't support annoying people just because you wonder what font a diagram uses.)

In general design, it's a sans-serif with wider than average proportions. The most similar designs which are vector fonts would be something like GrilliType [GT America Extended/Expanded](http://www.gt-america.com) (you'd want to switch in the simpler 'g'), [Helvetica Neue 63 Extended](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/) or Univers 63.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't actually be all that difficult to recreate this font yourself. Your image appears to have almost every digit and letter (both uppercase and lowercase, apart from Q maybe), so you won't have to create many of them from scratch. I'm not a lawyer, but as I understand it, glyph shapes aren't protected by copyright so there's nothing to stop you doing this.

There are online tools that can be used to build pixel fonts directly inside your browser, such as [bitfontmaker2](https://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/). It didn't take long to create the first few characters:

[image: screenshot of font preview from bitfontmaker2]

If you want to carry on building this font, follow the link to BitFontMaker2, click the data import/export button (the rightmost icon in the menu bar) and paste in the following:

`{"48":[0,0,0,0,0,248,388,324,292,276,268,248,0,0,0,0],"49":[0,0,0,0,0,32,48,32,32,32,32,248,0,0,0,0],"50":[0,0,0,0,0,248,260,256,240,8,4,508,0,0,0,0],"51":[0,0,0,0,0,248,260,256,224,256,260,248,0,0,0,0],"52":[0,0,0,0,0,192,160,144,136,508,128,128,0,0,0,0],"65":[0,0,0,0,0,112,136,260,260,508,260,260,0,0,0,0],"66":[0,0,0,0,0,252,260,260,252,260,260,252,0,0,0,0],"67":[0,0,0,0,0,240,264,4,4,4,264,240,0,0,0,0],"68":[0,0,0,0,0,124,132,260,260,260,132,124,0,0,0,0],"69":[0,0,0,0,0,508,4,4,60,4,4,508,0,0,0,0],"name":"1986CAD","copy":"","letterspace":"64","basefont_size":"490","basefont_left":"62","basefont_top":"0","basefont":"Arial","basefont2":"","monospace":true,"monospacewidth":"8"}`

Comment: Nice tool. That looks like a fun project to recreate the entire font +1

Comment: Bitmap fonts are amazingly fast to do. Even faster to copy.